# Connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive

Tags: visual-studio-code, pty

After installing VSCode, I started receiving this certain notification saying

> The connection to the terminal's pty host process is unresponsive, the terminals may stop working.

[image: screenshot]

The notification won't disappear until I click the restart button. But despite clicking this, no changes occurs and the notification pops up again after few seconds.

This problem caused my terminal to stop working and running node applications impossible.

Comment: problem may have returned with VS Code 1.78.1 (according to a non-answer posted as an answer.)

Comment: Same here, seems as if the bug persists with 1.79.
My details:
Version: 1.79.0 (user setup)
Commit: b380da4ef1ee00e224a15c1d4d9793e27c2b6302
Date: 2023-06-07T14:26:35.552Z
Electron: 22.5.5
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

Comment: Can confirm in 1.79 in Linux (Fedora). And seems to happen after using (connecting and disconnecting) from VPN.

Answer (score 18):

This is how I solved the issue:

- Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` (or Cmd + Shift + P on macOS) to open the command palette.
- Type "Reload Window" and select the "`Developer: Reload Window`" option. This will reload the Visual Studio Code window.
- Once the window is reloaded, open a new terminal by clicking on the plus icon in the terminal panel or using the shortcut Ctrl + ` (backtick).

After this, my terminal started working normally.

Comment: This works for me, but I have to do it every time I (re-)start VS Code. Is there a way to fix permanently, without rolling back a version? Using 1.79.2.

Comment: Still encountering this in VS Code v1.81.1, on MacOS Monterey.
Also had to Cmd+Shift+P and use "Developer: Reload Window" 

Answer (score 13):

Look up the extension "Dev Container" -> uninstall it -> reload VS Code-> reinstall the extension.

Hope this fixes it for you as well.

Comment: This worked for me! (Win10, VSCode 1.79.2)

Comment: Works for me on Debian 12 + KDE + VSCoe 1.79

Comment: This also worked for me - Windows 10, VSCode 1.79.2.   What's confusing is that the workspace I was having this problem in is just a local scratch/playground workspace which had never been connected to devcontainer or a repository (I have created a new repo for it since resolving the issue).

Comment: Worked for Vscode 1.85.1 too

Answer (score 9):

Same problem using version 1.79. Solved by downgrading the version.

Comment: command in fedora 38: `sudo dnf remove code -y && sudo dnf install code-1.78.2 -y`

Answer (score 6):

This is known issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7964

The fix will be included in the next `1.76` stable release, that is expected to be released in the first week of March 2023.

In the meantime you could either switch to the insiders builds or revert to the `1.74.3` version.

Answer (score 1):

same problem with 1.79 - downgrading to former version makes wsl extension imcompatible, gradle java applications stopped working on wsl - not sure if this is related

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue in 1.79.2 (windows 10)
Just closed all the windows in VSC and could launch a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

Simply Kill the terminal and wait a minute. In my case it's working perfectly in MacOS :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).